# Автоматический выход из профиля на сайте

Tags: php

Делаю автовыход на сайте. Пользователь логинится, через 15 мин *Cookies* удалились.
Делаю через функции.

Но при авторизации, с первого раза **нет** авторизации, пишется только «кука». Второй раз вводим логин/пароль — авторизовываемся.
Автовыход, вроде бы, работает.

Код такой:
авторизация...

```
AutoLogout();
Header("Location: /account");
```

Почему не авторизовывается с первого раза? Может быть, есть иные способы реализации автовыхода?

Comment: Ошибка такая - `Ошибка`

Comment: Проблема во входе или выходе? Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, подробней, ничего не понял. Время жизни кук 15 мин? Что значит "автовыход"? "С первого раз нет авторизации", это как?

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Можно в архив!!!